# I have package key value error

Tags: errors, packages

On my CV template this error is showing but I can not fin the error, could somebody help me?

```
Package keyvalue Error: Unknown option 'vargreek-shape' for package

 
‪/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math-xetex.sty, 569‬
(keyvalue)                unicode-math-xetex.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.569 \ProcessKeysOptions {unicode-math}
```

In the following, I have the packages:

```
\documentclass[english]{cv-style}   
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pagecolor} % for the color of the telefon 
\definecolor{mygray}{gray}{0.6} % define color
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\fancyfoot[CO]{\leftmark}


\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}

\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ marvosym }
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{genealogytree}
\usepackage{tikz}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example, instead of a code snippet.

Comment: that error was comon four or five years ago, you seem to be using an old file somewhere, see if there is an update or simply search for `vargreek-shape` and delete that.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=Package+keyvalue+Error%3A+Unknown+option+%27vargreek-shape%27+for+package